# Compute Mean Directional Accuracy with R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm working in R with a dataframe that has two variables: the actual time series value of a stock and its daily sentiment score and i want to understand the accuracy of the prediction. 
Is there a way to compute the Mean Directional Accuracy with R?

Comment: You should provide a small sample of your data - it will help get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using base R functions for lagged difference (`diff`), sign extraction (`sign`), and `mean`, you can create a user function to do this for two vectors of data:

```
MDirAcc <- function(Actual, Forecast, lag=1) {
    return( mean(sign(diff(Actual, lag=lag))==sign(diff(Forecast, lag=lag))) )
}
```

The `lag` value allows you to do this for daily data evaluated at other intervals.